# How to create self-referenced association field

Tags: go, orm

I'm trying to create self-reference field using [gorm](https://github.com/jinzhu/gorm):

```
type Post struct {
  ID        uint      `gorm:"primary_key" json:"id"`
  Post      *Post     `json:"post" xml:"post" sql:"default:null"`
}
db.AutoMigrate(&Post{})
```

Column `post_id` is not created in DB. Tried several struct field names, no luck.

Which is the correct way to handle self-refrenced associations?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Gorm magic isn't in the association (foreign key) part but in the data part.

Gorm will do the sql joins to retrieve the related `Post` row based on `PostID` It will then store that data in the nested `Post` field in `Post`.

If you only provide `Post` without `PostID` Gorm will do nothing as there is no foreign key for it to work with.

```
type Post struct {
  ID        uint      `gorm:"primary_key" json:"id"`
  Post      *Post     `json:"post" xml:"post" sql:"default:null"`
  PostID    uint      `json:"post_id" xml:"post_id"`
}
db.AutoMigrate(&Post{})
```